# Roadmap to study (Deligne) Algebraic geometry over Tannakian categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, tannakian-category

> I would like to know the way to proceed in the first lecture of Deligne's Le groupe fondamental de la droite projective moins trois points.
>
> General advices for reading Deligne's paper.
>
> What should I know before reading Deligne's paper?
>
> What should I have in mind while reading the paper?
>
> Useful tools for reading the paper (for example Know what the yoga of motives is.)?
>
> What are some references for algebraic geometry (if any) over tannakian categories (other than Deligne's Le groupe fondamental de la droite projective moins trois points).

Fell free to comment to improve the question.

Comment: The syllabus from a STAGE seminar on this topic may be useful: http://math.mit.edu/nt/STAGEFall2014.pdf.

Comment: An abstraction of these ideas is found in the work of Toën and Vaquié's "Au Dessous de Spec Z." This is called relative algebraic geometry and I think this paper is a joy to read and useful for understanding what you are asking about.